# react does not update localstorage value based on state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using react to switch between light and dark mode in  my website . I also want the theme to persist using localstorage . The problem is that while clicking on switch to toggle the theme the corresponding localstorage theme value does not update. I know that state updates are asynchronous but I want to fix this .

My code:

```
const [darkMode , setDarkMode] = useState(false);

  //change theme 
  const toggleTheme = ()=>{ 

    setDarkMode(!darkMode);
    const root = window.document.documentElement;
    if(localStorage.getItem("isDark")=== null){
      localStorage.setItem("isDark",darkMode);
    }else{
      localStorage.setItem("isDark",darkMode);
    }
    root.classList.toggle('dark');

  }
```

I tried using async await but the result was the same .

Comment: Duplicate: [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: Solution: `const newValue = !darkMode;` and `setDarkMode(newValue);` and `localStorage.setItem("isDark", newValue);`

Comment: As a side note, your `if... else...` conditional does not make sense as you are going to do `localStorage.setItem("isDark",darkMode);` regardless of the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use state variable `darkMode` just after updating it via `setDarkMode` due to its async nature. You could use `useEffect` hook but that wont be the best way imo just to solve a simple problem like this. Instead you can use it this way

```
// Initialize variable from localstorage value
const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(
  () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("isDark")) ?? false
);

//change theme
const toggleTheme = () => {
  const updatedDarkMode = !darkMode;

  setDarkMode(updatedDarkMode);
  const root = window.document.documentElement;
  localStorage.setItem("isDark", updatedDarkMode);

  root.classList.toggle("dark");
};
```

Comment: The problem is that after I refresh my page in darkmode , the first time I toggle theme the localstorage value does not switch

Comment: @vasilis123 try the updated solution..

Comment: It finally worked

Answer (score 2):

You can use `useEffect` in order to keep watch on `darkMode`.

Here, `useEffect` will be called every time when darkMode value is updated. Hence, setting the `localStorage` value inside. And I removed `if.. else..` condition as I guess there is no need of that, if you feel you can keep it.

```
const [darkMode , setDarkMode] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("isDark", darkMode);
}, darkMode);
 
// change theme 
const toggleTheme = ()=>{ 
  setDarkMode(!darkMode);
  const root = window.document.documentElement;
  root.classList.toggle('dark');
}
```

Comment: This always sets darkmode to true

Comment: Can you please check the value of `darkMode` inside useEffect by console it and tell me.

Comment: Also `root.classList.toggle('dark');` you are passing value `dark` directly from here. Is there any reason.

Comment: I am really busy rn . I will update later

Comment: Bhaddauriya The mode is correctly logged but on refresh it is always light mode and sets localstorage to light mode . The problem is that after I refresh my page in darkmode , the first time I toggle theme the localstorage value does not switch